# Use Xlib inside Qt

Tags: qt, xlib

I would like to be able to modify the Qt window's properties with Xlib fonctions.

I tried using QX11Info to get the display and QWidget::winId to get the window.

```
Display *display  = QX11Info::display();
int window = QWidget::winId ();

XMoveResizeWindow(display, window, 100, 100, 400, 400);
```

But it didn't work.
I thought that maybe the window `QWidget::winId ()` returns isn't the main one of the application. So I tried to modify its parent to see if it was the right window.

```
Display *display  = QX11Info::display();
int window = QWidget::winId ();

unsigned int nbChildren;
Window root,parent,*children;
XQueryTree(display, window, &root, &parent, &children, &nbChildren);

XMoveResizeWindow(display, parent, 100, 100, 400, 400);
```

But it didn't work either.
I also tried `XStoreName(display, window, "test Qt");`for both example. The problem could have been that the window was not resisable.

I know I should do this kind of things with Qt directly but I am trying with easy fonctions to see if I can get the right window id. My goal is to change the window properties, using customs xlib intern atoms.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using these functions before the window was displayed.

```cpp
Display *display  = QX11Info::display();
int window = QWidget::winId ();

XMoveResizeWindow(display, window, 100, 100, 400, 400);
```

This works if it is used after `show()`.